# sed to delete all lines except last line based on string match

Tags: shell, ssh, sed, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

Got `autorized_keys` with old key from a specific user say `alice` and would like to retain last amended public key & delete rest of them.

Here is example content of autorized_keys file:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEA0YnNYVo/lHtSLtDUpQIqgS8WIpoBA7NRfaheQZXjqOjDMmBZA0cJy+ng3kmUuh5SbNapjaAYFwMHjLv6biHAasWgE77rJYXN8+JpHi/JwuXUnVUTwHrKXvkMr0sPgDxCEZO15GtiJwVPfmxpl3RBB/we5a+A6fhvXCyk/dxQRdU= alice-publickey
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDp6d0GmH5Q+lbx832n2W43Ikx8cpTeM8MRQ1yJmnhzaCSkQk9jWkwB5Msvj7uR923k0qLCZQ4ZbdPQ7liK9+Ks/7c0yDrBkU1KVOBNDQD1ck9Iwo2qwsS72b1kf4zeNKVJWkKBcFg7qxOmjIy9wNJ0XhbHmo/9gkp/hoOY3g0I5tExIlVdTH+uhEmOerghChTHTWU/kymZW0yYbDKl9zyPEDY9Hf/0Mt6g2dz+q3/cfcwCIZIeR5/Fjt7xXbt+fqmaiws1veGacw60u8ouMJ4DL9CcXRUbZHdEY4v2yIcEZRXMv9Q/6s0TcuC9s6Z5n2RzV8eW3RCZuzMWmYlkcA/H bob-publickey
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAsB3XsrmTHWygTrL8dT/Z5+qjjXfPxH7IPlyFZt0QcHA1a16g0ZPeEMB1RUu90vtbEvKjq+hAAANeLcmVW85i8LSsO3xcuCGTFNVNx2up7Fv7YxiHMJpfQqyiBW09HixrPiu+9Wl/olTB9kPu+fZ/jRqok3ZTARnQDoE2g1RWnNU= alice@mcosmac
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC2UFK8Y7mODUZ7a2glErZbKk9hUy1pCOiGz4arAlTBiJ884vrjGaYNGFyWiNvqNKxLWn6Cul1eyPF1M/Z6l6QE3biJgJPln2ZZIoMcsNiCrFl0x5tUdnyVnVGz5pZTI1/0IFFLE4jbW2grMHOC7z+ik3WOD5aTj8pUWeTIeppMKLwjnJhm0ALsmLZqhtwnhgLSg9m4NQmcLWt5s0P/Z91hUKw2tY5iV9yOu5tS+oTMoeV7ays9MXM9ozpehLhsbqn98O7k2UpQzoWEo093lAjzydnBICd5tKdVJyGcyi3BLY4xhU+dnJ9NIUuYtnLZEhAGCbOQEGNivkxDQv1ccRTx trudy@newMacs
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDPbEzZDSZNKdGsH0sP10abmosX0yFquCEx2ibNzmh0AvvsR6pbA/pdl1i9XqIJlDBustWfmnChXEQz9Nft5LbM/moR6DAe7Wd70kmY8CreGgZ2kF8KCZ3bTkKYfO5PexKRCZ8IFRs6xswbfV0DJOmGnNo+wKOFDK/J7GVd9e1u6FebSo/Nr0QN/maXKN+Tc57GnV+j34ihD9PoRmfGYRIjm/vMkfUB9l1fZDEawdMO+Ats+G9gSvlhIm4TSP4sHk+zUJJff+j6ubMsGW0Flh4YjVJMMSU9vrpsTS5WiEbsZVxuWkrd+9jMo5RGDoWt2HADo4Dup0DlyM1pj2u1zbfl alice@brandNew
```

Below option looks to help me filter with sed & as we know with `-i` option we can do in-file edits directly. But I am unsure on # of old keys registered on machine for user `alice`.

```
grep alice authorized_keys | sed '1,2d'
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDPbEzZDSZNKdGsH0sP10abmosX0yFquCEx2ibNzmh0AvvsR6pbA/pdl1i9XqIJlDBustWfmnChXEQz9Nft5LbM/moR6DAe7Wd70kmY8CreGgZ2kF8KCZ3bTkKYfO5PexKRCZ8IFRs6xswbfV0DJOmGnNo+wKOFDK/J7GVd9e1u6FebSo/Nr0QN/maXKN+Tc57GnV+j34ihD9PoRmfGYRIjm/vMkfUB9l1fZDEawdMO+Ats+G9gSvlhIm4TSP4sHk+zUJJff+j6ubMsGW0Flh4YjVJMMSU9vrpsTS5WiEbsZVxuWkrd+9jMo5RGDoWt2HADo4Dup0DlyM1pj2u1zbfl alice@brandNew
```

Is there a way to delete all old keys of `alice` except last one in-place holding this string match of `alice` ?

Comment: `awk '/alice/{x=$0} END{print x}' file`?

Comment: Looks like above just gets me last line, and filters out all matching & non matching entry on string `alice`

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove a line with alice when you have another alice in the file.
Repeat until all alices except the last one are removed.

```
sed -rz ':a;s/(\n|^)[^\n]*alice[^\n]*\n(.*alice)/\1\2/;ta' authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` does not really have a good concept of "last of the matching lines"; but this is relatively easy with Awk.

```
awk '{ l[++n] = $0 }
  /alice/ { alice=NR }
  END { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) if (alice == i || !(l[i] ~ /alice/)) print l[i] }' file >file.new
```

This slurps the entire file into memory, so if the file is really big, maybe look for a different solution.

Awk out of the box does not have the capability to overwrite its input file, though GNU Awk has an `-i inplace` option which works roughly like `sed -i`

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a job for `ed` than it is `sed`, because `ed` has ways to find matches starting from the end of the file:

```
ed -s keys.txt <<'EOF'
1;?alice?-1 g/alice/d
w
EOF
```

will **d**elete every line matching `alice` in the range from the first line to the one before the last occurrence of `alice` and then **w**rite the file back to disk.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/alice/=' file | sed '$d;s/$/d/' | sed -f - -i file
```

Find the line numbers of `Alice` keys.

Remove the last one and convert all others into sed delete command.

Apply the above commands to the original file.

Comment: This just works well, if I do this on same machine where file exists. But if link it to `ssh` command, its **deleting all** `alice` entries from file. Does it work differently when executed over remote machine?
eg : `ssh alice@targetMachine sed -n '/alice/=' file | sed '$d;s/$/d/' | sed -f - -i file`

Comment: The command in your comment would only run the first `sed` remotely, and the others locally. How to correctly run a pipeline remotely is a separate question, but also a very common FAQ. The simplest, most robust way is to pass the script as a single-quoted here document to ssh, like `ssh user@remote <<'EOF'` _(newline) (your commands here) (newline)_ `EOF` _(newline)_

Answer (score 1):

Consider an `awk` solution:

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR {if (/alice/) last=FNR; next} !/alice/ || FNR == last' file file

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDp6d0GmH5Q+lbx832n2W43Ikx8cpTeM8MRQ1yJmnhzaCSkQk9jWkwB5Msvj7uR923k0qLCZQ4ZbdPQ7liK9+Ks/7c0yDrBkU1KVOBNDQD1ck9Iwo2qwsS72b1kf4zeNKVJWkKBcFg7qxOmjIy9wNJ0XhbHmo/9gkp/hoOY3g0I5tExIlVdTH+uhEmOerghChTHTWU/kymZW0yYbDKl9zyPEDY9Hf/0Mt6g2dz+q3/cfcwCIZIeR5/Fjt7xXbt+fqmaiws1veGacw60u8ouMJ4DL9CcXRUbZHdEY4v2yIcEZRXMv9Q/6s0TcuC9s6Z5n2RzV8eW3RCZuzMWmYlkcA/H bob-publickey
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC2UFK8Y7mODUZ7a2glErZbKk9hUy1pCOiGz4arAlTBiJ884vrjGaYNGFyWiNvqNKxLWn6Cul1eyPF1M/Z6l6QE3biJgJPln2ZZIoMcsNiCrFl0x5tUdnyVnVGz5pZTI1/0IFFLE4jbW2grMHOC7z+ik3WOD5aTj8pUWeTIeppMKLwjnJhm0ALsmLZqhtwnhgLSg9m4NQmcLWt5s0P/Z91hUKw2tY5iV9yOu5tS+oTMoeV7ays9MXM9ozpehLhsbqn98O7k2UpQzoWEo093lAjzydnBICd5tKdVJyGcyi3BLY4xhU+dnJ9NIUuYtnLZEhAGCbOQEGNivkxDQv1ccRTx trudy@newMacs
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDPbEzZDSZNKdGsH0sP10abmosX0yFquCEx2ibNzmh0AvvsR6pbA/pdl1i9XqIJlDBustWfmnChXEQz9Nft5LbM/moR6DAe7Wd70kmY8CreGgZ2kF8KCZ3bTkKYfO5PexKRCZ8IFRs6xswbfV0DJOmGnNo+wKOFDK/J7GVd9e1u6FebSo/Nr0QN/maXKN+Tc57GnV+j34ihD9PoRmfGYRIjm/vMkfUB9l1fZDEawdMO+Ats+G9gSvlhIm4TSP4sHk+zUJJff+j6ubMsGW0Flh4YjVJMMSU9vrpsTS5WiEbsZVxuWkrd+9jMo5RGDoWt2HADo4Dup0DlyM1pj2u1zbfl alice@brandNew
```

**To save change inline**

For `gnu-awk`:

```bash
awk -i inplace 'NR==FNR {if (/alice/) last=FNR; next}
   !/alice/ || FNR == last' file file
```

For `posix awk`:

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR {if (/alice/) last=FNR; next}
   !/alice/ || FNR == last' file file > file.out && mv file.out file
```

Comment: This is more succinct than my version, but reads the input file twice.

Comment: Yeah either we read file twice or read content in memory